# How to make dropdown (dropdown content) to show below each button when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to solve this issue for some days now but just giving me a lot of time to crack my brain and yet doesn't get the solution to it.
What I want to solve is that, when I click on each button, I want its dropdown to show just below its own button rather than all the dropdown showing at the left side of the screen and secondly, when it show just below its button, the content should change.

Thanks.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    let dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      let openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
nav {
display: flex;
}

.dropbtn {
  font-size: 12px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 155px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  opacity: .9;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: blue;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: ;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>                   
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" id="active" onclick="myFunction()">new
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
            <a href="#">link 1</a>
            <a href="#">link 2</a>
            <a href="#">link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">fresh
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
            <a href="#">link 4</a>
            <a href="#">link 5</a>
            <a href="#">link 6</a>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">naija
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
            <a href="#">link 7</a>
            <a href="#">link 8</a>
            <a href="#">link 9</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
</nav>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a live `HTMLCollection` which contains every descendant element which has the specified class name or names. `HTMLCollection` i.e. is an object.

Comment: use `querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content')` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code is doing right now is creating three dropdown elements. Then, when a button is clicked, you are executing `myFunction()`, which gets `#myDropdown`. An element's [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) is, quoting the MDN Docs, "unique in a document". However, you have three elements with the same ID. So, when you execute `document.getElementById("myDropdown")` on line two of your JS code, it will find the **first instance** of `#myDropdown` and toggle the `show` class on that one element.

The provided code has the following changes:

1. **Removed [inline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)**. It is better practice to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline events like `onclick` in your HTML.
2. Better `let` and `const` usages.

```js
const dropdowns = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content"));
const dropdownButtons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('dropbtn'));

let currentDropdown = 0;
let dropdownAmount = 0;

dropdownButtons.forEach(function(dropdownBtn, index) {
  dropdownBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    dropdowns[index].classList.toggle('show');
    currentDropdown = index;
    dropdownAmount++;
    
    if (dropdownAmount > 1) { // closes other dropdowns if more than one is open
      for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        const openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show') && i !== currentDropdown) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
      dropdownAmount = 1;
    }
  });
});

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    const openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
    dropdownAmount = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
nav {
display: flex;
}

.dropbtn {
  font-size: 12px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 155px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  opacity: .9;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: blue;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: ;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>                   
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" id="active">new</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">link 1</a>
            <a href="#">link 2</a>
            <a href="#">link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">fresh</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">link 4</a>
            <a href="#">link 5</a>
            <a href="#">link 6</a>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn"><i>naija</i></button> <!-- demonstration for op's problem -->
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">link 7</a>
            <a href="#">link 8</a>
            <a href="#">link 9</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
</nav>
```

**EDIT:** Fixed the code so that child elements of the `.dropbtn`s also open the dropdown. The `.dropbtn` click event was working, but then it also fired the `window` click event. The `window` click event checked the event target, which was not a button, so it closed all the dropdowns. Now, if the `.dropbtn` click event is fired, [`e.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) is called which prevents the `window` click event from firing.

Comment: Thank you so very much @bub . Your answer really does it and its working. I really appreciate your effort towards this, it makes my day.

Comment: I just discovered that if any other button or container is placed/addede inside the button with the class dropbtn, if such added button or container is clicked, the dropdown-content does not show.  example <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">naija  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">link 7</a>
            <a href="#">link 8</a>
            <a href="#">link 9</a>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: That should be fixed now. Please check the code and see if it works. Thank you!